# Finding border of a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

We are given a binary search tree; we need to find out its border.

So, if the binary tree is

```
           10
       /         \
     50           150
    /  \         /   \
  25    75     200    20
 / \           /      / \
15 35        120    155 250
```

It should print out `50 25 15 35 120 155 250 20 150 10`.

If the binary tree is

```
               10
           /         \
         50           150
        /  \         /   
      25    75     200   
     / \   / \    
    15 35 65 30
```

It should be like `50 25 15 35 65 30 200 150 10`.

How can this be done? Does generalising this for a binary tree make the problem any harder?

Any help through links will also be appreciated.

P.S.: please see that the pattern does not start from root but from the left (in this case). It might also start with right, but it always ends with the root.

Comment: I did figure out the algorithm a bit.We need to use a combination of DFS and a BFS to get it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is a modified depth-first traversal where the node's values are only printed/returned if either 1) the node is a leaf node or 2) the node is along the "outer path" of the tree, where "outer path" is defined as

A node is a part of the "outer path" if you arrived at the node by following all of the left (or right) paths from the root, or if the node is the right (or left) child of a parent node that was itself a part of the "outer path" but had no left (or right) children.

If you know how to code DFS, then the modification here could be implemented by checking a few extra conditions during the traversal.

Comment: It's more complicated than that, due to 75 (leaf node) not being in the first tree.  I think what the OP basically wants the nodes that fall along the triangle that follows the leftmost branch, then the deepest level, then the rightmost branch.  And that is not a reasonable task for a binary tree.

Comment: Strike that, I'm wrong too.  What bizarre requirements.  I don't think two examples cut it, we need the specification.

Comment: Well then I think you could still follow the same basic algorithm, just with modified conditions - keep track of the max depth of the tree, only count leaf nodes as a part of the border if their depth == max depth OR the node is the deepest node in the left/right sub-tree. Might be easier to keep track of max-depth with BFS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it matters whether this a binary tree or not. I think the walk algorithm would be the same either way.

Start with the left subtree, and do a modified breadth first walk that prints a node only if it's the left sibling or an edge. this will print the left siblings until it hits the edges, then print the leaves out.

Then you do a modified depth first walk on the right tree that prints either the right sibling or a leaf. This will print all the right subtree leaves, and then the right siblings.

Comment: Same solution strikedto me also. But there is a flaw in the solution. When you walk the left subtree last element will be a leaf. so it gets printed also when we print all the other leaves.Same thing happens when we walk on right subtree.How do u eliminate duplicating the two leaves?

Answer (score 0):

```
printBorder(node *n){

   printLeft(n);   O(log n)
   printBottom(n); O(n)
   printRight(n);  O(log n)
}

printBottom(node *n)
{
  int h = treeHeight(n);
  printBottomHelper(n, 0);
}
printBottomHelper(n, h, max)
{
   if(h == max) {
    print n->data
  }
   printBottomHelper(n->left, h+1, max);
   printBottomHelper(n->right, h+1, max);
}
printLeft(node *n)
{
  while(n!= null){
   node *l = n->left;
   l!= null ? print l->data:1
   n =l;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two booleans to say what to print.

Call printBorder(root, true, true) to begin.  Edit : Doesn't print root at the end, but at beginning, should special case that.

```
function printBorder(
Node node, bool printLeft, bool printRight, int height, const int MAX_HEIGHT) {
  if (printLeft || printRight ||
  (node.left == null && node.right == null && height == MAX_HEIGHT)) {
    print node;
  }
  if (node.left) printBorder(node.left, printLeft, printRight && node.right==null)
  if (node.right) printBorder(node.right, printLeft && node.left == null, printRight)
}
```

Where MAX_HEIGHT found by maxdepth(root, 0);

```
int maxdepth(Node node, int height) {
  if (node == null) return height;
  return max(maxdepth(node.left, height+1), maxdepth(node.right, height+1))
}
```

Comment: Where is the condition that would now allow to print number 75 in the example tree provided by the question? For node 75 , node.left is null and node. right is null . So irrespective of printLeft and printRight booleans your algorithm would print a node if its left and right are null(but it need not be a leaf right?)

Comment: Hmm, thats right. I guess, i would have to do a first pass to determine the max depth, and then pass that with the printBorder. To be honest, only now @matt 's comments made sense to me.